# What to look for with 'Only variable references should be returned by reference'?

Tags: php, arrays, reference

My function is used to provide an array by reference and then returning a reference to a part of a multidimensional array:

```
function &find(&$refArray, $key, $value) {
  ...
  if ($condition) {
     return $array
  }
}
```

I didn't include the code because my code includes a lot of reliance on other functions defined in my code base that would make it very convoluted.

The function works as expected.  It returns a reference to an array but it displays a notice:

`Notice:  Only variable references should be returned by reference in Arr.php on line 46`

Line 46 references the closing bracket of the find function.  From searching, this error is usually displayed when you try to return a bool but it returns a reference to the array and nowhere in my code do I return anything but an array.

**Resolution**: This was caused by the function not returning anything if the condition was not met which fails the reference check as pointed out by Barmar (Thank You).  I resolved this by adding this to the bottom of the function:

```
$return = false;
return $return;
```

This way it always returns a reference to a variable.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, can you provide a simple example that does it?

Comment: @Barmar, I'll see if I can write a short function to reproduce it.

Comment: @Barmar, yeah I can't reproduce it either so I wonder what is causing it.  So I don't know if it is a bug or not as it returns a referenced array as expected.

Comment: aren't you trying to return a reference to a variable declared inside the function (ie to a variable that gets out of scope as soon as the function returns)?

Comment: @fpierrat, $array ends up referencing a $refArray[key].  It works as expected, I was able to do `$ref = &find($arr, $key, $value)` and `$ref` reflects any changes made to `$arr` and vice versa.  It just displays this notice.

Comment: does something like `static $temp= $refArray[key]; return $temp;` help?

Comment: Do all code paths through the function lead to that `return $array` statement? Or is it possible to fall off the end of the function without executing it?

Comment: or `$temp=  & $refArray[key];` ? then $temp is a reference, you can return it as such...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `return $array;` statement is probably inside an `if` statement (or some other conditional). If the test is false, it will skip over the `if` statement, and return when it gets to the end of the function. Since there's no `return $variable` statement there, you'll get this warning.

I was able to reproduce your situation with the following example:

```
  function &find($test) {
    $array = array(1, 2, 3);
    if ($test) {
      return $array;
    }
  }
```

`find(true)` works fine, `find(false)` generates the warning.

The clue that this is the reason is that the line number in the warning is the closing `}`, not a line containing `return`. So it must be referring to the implicit `return undefined` that occurs when you reach the end of a function.

Comment: You're right.  I definitely see the issue now that you point this out.  It is during recursion that it is not returning anything.  I fixed this by adding at the very bottom of the function: `$return = false; return $return;`